# Emacs hung with Error running timer 'blink-cursor-start'

Tags: init-file, debugging

I just installed a fresh Ubuntu 17.10 on a Dell XPS 15, and then installed Emacs from the repos with apt-get in the normal way.

The moment I start Emacs, I get the error message

```
Error running timer 'blink-cursor-start': (wrong-type-argument listp 0.5)
```

It then refuses all keyboard input; for example `C-x d` gets the error message `Wrong type argument: listp 10`

Is there a way to disable (from outside Emacs) whatever it is that calls `blink-cursor-start` so that I can at least try using Emacs to find and fix the problem? I have not installed my .emacs file yet, so this is raw behaviour as-installed.

Has anyone seen this behaviour before? Or know what the problem might be?

[Edit] I managed to run Emacs without the suggested -Q just enough to open the messages buffer with the mouse and grab the contents. Then quit and run again with -Q and paste the message contents into a file to save it. This is what it says:

```
Loading 00debian-vars...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50asymptote.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50autoconf.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...
Loading debian-ispell...
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-default.el (source)...done
Loading debian-ispell...done
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-dicts.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50latex-cjk-common.el (source)...
Loading cjk-enc...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50latex-cjk-common.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50latex-cjk-thai.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50texlive-lang-english.el (source)...done
For information about GNU Emacs and the GNU system, type C-h C-a.
setq: Wrong type argument: listp, 10
Error running timer ‘blink-cursor-start’: (wrong-type-argument listp 0.5) [2 times]
setq: Wrong type argument: listp, 0.7
Error running timer ‘blink-cursor-start’: (wrong-type-argument listp 0.5) [5 times]
Mark set
Error running timer ‘blink-cursor-start’: (wrong-type-argument listp 0.5)
setq: Wrong type argument: listp, 0.7 [2 times]
Error running timer ‘blink-cursor-start’: (wrong-type-argument listp 0.5)
setq: Wrong type argument: listp, 0.7
Error running timer ‘blink-cursor-start’: (wrong-type-argument listp 0.5) [4 times]
```

Anyone know where `blink-cursor-start` is called?

Comment: Does it also happen with emacs -Q

Comment: Cool, thank you. It comes up just fine that way. Weird -- in all my decades of using Emacs I've never had to use -Q or even noticed it existed. It's equivalent to --no-splash, which is fine; and also to --no-site-file --- which 'site-file' does this refer to? The system-wide init.el? Some other init.el? Or the debian-startup.el (I'm using Ubuntu)? Or my own .emacs? I'm interested in tracking down whatever has been broken in this release

Comment: I just edited the original to add the log of startup echoes in messages.

Comment: With regards to your question as to whether anyone knows where `blink-cursor-start` is called, a quick grep of the source code should give you all references.  And, we can see that is only called one time in `frame.el` at the tail end of `blink-cursor--start-idle-timer`.  Since all current versions of Emacs have `blink-cursor-mode` enabled by default, it is reasonable to assume that you have a user-configuration somewhere  that is loading and causing the problem, or you have a broken installation of Emacs.  If it is not a big deal, then just remove your Emacs installation and build a new one.

Comment: Also, verify the version of Emacs that you are using with `M-x emacs-version`.  Some computers may have several versions installed at different locations, and people think they are using one version when in fact they are using a different version.  If there is no good reason to use an older version of Emacs, then you should be using the latest stable release -- i.e., Emacs 25.  The next version (Emacs 26) will hopefully be released soon.  Creating a recipe starting from `emacs -Q` is necessary so that others can replicate your issue and also for you to verify configuration is not the culprit.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Grepping the source isn't easy, as the Ubuntu packaged installation has it all gzipped, and spread over multiple trees, so knowing about frame.el is a great start. It's possibly my .emacs, except that is working fine on a dozen other machines running Ubuntu; but perhaps Ubuntu 17.x has included something new — the other machines are all 16.x. No big deal to reinstall, but it's from the Ubuntu repos, not from source...I haven't built Emacs from source for over a decade. And this is a brand new install, so there is only one copy, fortunately.

Comment: Definitely not my .emacs anyway: renaming it and firing up Emacs gets me the same problem as before. If I eval-buffer my .emacs, I get all my own features OK. So no progress, except that I have ruled out any user configuration. My guess is that it's the hardware, so the next step is to see if an older version works. Or compile my own, which I'd rather not have to do.

Comment: Just upgraded a completely different system to Ubuntu 17.10 — and guess what? Emacs is still broken as shipped: same error message as before, and same fix (emacs -Q). Fortunately this is temporary, as it's the last machine to migrate off Ubuntu, never to return: I have switched dev and prod to Mint 18, which despite using Ubuntu repos, has Emacs running perfectly. I'd report the bug, but I've seen no other references.

Comment: Sad to report, but this bug now shows up in Mint 19 as well, so it's clearly in something installed by the OS/package which has been added to Mint from Ubuntu. Disabling startup with -Q works, but I need my custom .emacs (which works perfectly if I open it and eval-buffer).

Comment: This problem still exists in Mint 19 and I am unable to trace it. It's not a .emacs problem (there is no .emacs); it's Emacs 25.2.2; and clearly not a Mint-only problem as it happens on other Ubuntus I have tried. If the problem is in frame.el as described above, how do I disable that?

Comment: I don't have an answer, I'm just posting to add another piece to the puzzle. I just upgraded my MacBook Pro to Catalina. Before this, I've had no problems with emacs. Now, when I start it without -Q, I have the 'blink-cursor-start' issue. It doesn't matter whether I'm starting emacs-app or the emacs you get if you do port install emacs +x11. Doing a (set debug-on-error) as the first statement in my .emacs, I get the following traceback. Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument listp 0.5) cdr(0.5) (setq time (cdr time)) (prog1 time (setq time (cdr time))) (car-safe (prog1 time (setq t

Comment: That looks like what I got too. Does anyone know where this can be reported such that someone will pay attention to it?